# Rails API Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js, omniauth

I am trying to implement Omniauth with Devise in Rails API with NuxtJS framework.

I did auth module connexion and user account creation with Omniauth method but i would like understand how redirect the user afer signin/signup, i am Rails developer and beginner with NuxtJS.

**BACKEND**

User model oauth registration method:

```
def self.from_facebook(auth)
 where(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider).first_or_create do |user|
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
  user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  Client.create(user: user)
 end
end
```

Registration controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Overrides
class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController
before_action :set_user_by_token, only: [:destroy, :update]
before_action :validate_sign_up_params, only: :create
before_action :validate_account_update_params, only: :update
skip_after_action :update_auth_header, only: [:create, :destroy]

def create
  build_resource

  unless @resource.present?
    raise DeviseTokenAuth::Errors::NoResourceDefinedError,
          "#{self.class.name} #build_resource does not define @resource,"\
          ' execution stopped.'
  end

  # give redirect value from params priority
  @redirect_url = params.fetch(
    :confirm_success_url,
    DeviseTokenAuth.default_confirm_success_url
  )

  # success redirect url is required
  if confirmable_enabled? && !@redirect_url
    return render_create_error_missing_confirm_success_url
  end

  # if whitelist is set, validate redirect_url against whitelist
  return render_create_error_redirect_url_not_allowed if blacklisted_redirect_url?

  # override email confirmation, must be sent manually from ctrl
  resource_class.set_callback('create', :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)
  resource_class.skip_callback('create', :after, :send_on_create_confirmation_instructions)

  if @resource.respond_to? :skip_confirmation_notification!
    # Fix duplicate e-mails by disabling Devise confirmation e-mail
    @resource.skip_confirmation_notification!
  end

  if @resource.save
    if params[:farmer]
      Farmer.create(
        user: @resource
      )
    else
      Client.create(
        user: @resource
      )
    end

    yield @resource if block_given?

    unless @resource.confirmed?
      # user will require email authentication
      @resource.send_confirmation_instructions({
        client_config: params[:config_name],
        redirect_url: @redirect_url
      })
    end

    if active_for_authentication?
      # email auth has been bypassed, authenticate user
      @client_id, @token = @resource.create_token
      @resource.save!
      update_auth_header
    end

    render_create_success
  else
    clean_up_passwords @resource
    render_create_error
  end
end

def update
  if @resource
    if @resource.send(resource_update_method, account_update_params)
      yield @resource if block_given?
      render_update_success
    else
      render_update_error
    end
  else
    render_update_error_user_not_found
  end
end

def destroy
  if @resource
    @resource.destroy
    yield @resource if block_given?
    render_destroy_success
  else
    render_destroy_error
  end
end

def sign_up_params
  params.permit(
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :email,
    :cellphone,
    :phone,
    :password,
    :password_confirmation,
    :birthdate
  )
end

def account_update_params
  params.permit(*params_for_resource(:account_update))
end

protected

def build_resource
  @resource            = resource_class.new(sign_up_params)
  @resource.provider   = provider

  # honor devise configuration for case_insensitive_keys
  if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(:email)
    @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email].try(:downcase)
  else
    @resource.email = sign_up_params[:email]
  end
end

def render_create_error_missing_confirm_success_url
  response = {
    status: 'error',
    data:   resource_data
  }
  message = I18n.t('devise_token_auth.registrations.missing_confirm_success_url')
  render_error(422, message, response)
end

def render_create_error_redirect_url_not_allowed
  response = {
    status: 'error',
    data:   resource_data
  }
  message = I18n.t('devise_token_auth.registrations.redirect_url_not_allowed', redirect_url: @redirect_url)
  render_error(422, message, response)
end

def render_create_success
  render json: {
    status: 'success',
    data:   resource_data
  }
end

def render_create_error
  render json: {
    status: 'error',
    data:   resource_data,
    errors: resource_errors
  }, status: 422
end

def render_update_success
  render json: {
    status: 'success',
    data:   resource_data
  }
end

def render_update_error
  render json: {
    status: 'error',
    errors: resource_errors
  }, status: 422
end

def render_update_error_user_not_found
  render_error(404, I18n.t('devise_token_auth.registrations.user_not_found'), status: 'error')
end

def render_destroy_success
  render json: {
    status: 'success',
    message: I18n.t('devise_token_auth.registrations.account_with_uid_destroyed', uid: @resource.uid)
  }
end

def render_destroy_error
  render_error(404, I18n.t('devise_token_auth.registrations.account_to_destroy_not_found'), status: 'error')
end

private

def resource_update_method
  if DeviseTokenAuth.check_current_password_before_update == :attributes
    'update_with_password'
  elsif DeviseTokenAuth.check_current_password_before_update == :password && account_update_params.key?(:password)
    'update_with_password'
  elsif account_update_params.key?(:current_password)
    'update_with_password'
  else
    'update_attributes'
  end
end

def validate_sign_up_params
  validate_post_data sign_up_params, I18n.t('errors.messages.validate_sign_up_params')
end

def validate_account_update_params
  validate_post_data account_update_params, I18n.t('errors.messages.validate_account_update_params')
end

def validate_post_data which, message
  render_error(:unprocessable_entity, message, status: 'error') if which.empty?
end

def active_for_authentication?
  !@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) || @resource.active_for_authentication?
end
end
end
```

Omniauth callbacks controller:

```
def facebook
@user = User.from_facebook(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

# NOTE: redirection here
end
```

**FRONTEND**

Stategie:

```
facebook: {
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    userinfo_endpoint: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=about,name,picture{url},email,birthday',
    redirect_uri:'http://localhost:3000/omniauth/facebook',
    scope: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday']
  }
```

Login method:

```
facebookLogin () {
    this.$auth.loginWith('facebook')
    .then((response) => {
      this.$toast.success({
        title: 'Connexion réussie',
        message: 'Vous vous êtes bien connecté.',
        position: 'bottom center',
        timeOut: 3000
      })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.$toast.error({
        title: 'Erreur',
        message: 'L\'email ou le mot de passe ne sont pas valides. Vérifiez votre saisie.',
        position: 'bottom center',
        timeOut: 8000
      })
    })
    .finally(() => this.$wait.end('signing in'))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

1. Omniauth callbacks controller is missing the redirect information (is that why that note is there?). If you're using Devise, it should say something like `sign_in_and_redirect @user` underneath the `@user = ...` line.
2. Devise comes with built in routes. To use them, you must include something like, `devise for :users` in your routes.rb file. Check out the "Devise_for magic" section on [this page](https://devhints.io/devise) to see an example of these built in routes. Note that you have to have some Devise models configured for this to work.
3. Run `rake routes` to see if the routes you have defined are what you're expecting.
4. If you can't figure it out, I also created a project using Omniauth and devise. You can view my code [here](https://github.com/eponsonby/coffee_shop_explorer).

Comment: Yes is that why my note here, i have my routes too and my omniauth work well in Rails but i need to redirect on my NuxtJS page with the user authentificate